# Issue with HtmlUnit on Android

Tags: java, android, htmlunit

I've been having an issue using HtmlUnit on Android.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    return true;
}
```

This simple code results in a force close and causes the following error:

```
04-15 20:07:28.266: E/dalvikvm(856): Could not find class 'com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient', referenced from method com.synkronus.deeproute.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground
```

And a little later:

```
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.synkronus.deeproute.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:204)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.synkronus.deeproute.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-15 20:07:30.031: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  ... 4 more
```

My confusion stems from the "Could not find class 'com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient'" error, which I'm getting even though I have added the HtmlUnit jars to my buildpath in Eclipse and I can clearly see the "missing" class file in my Referenced Libraries.

Comment: Do you have a question? The error message is fairly straightforward. (Android doesn't include com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient. Have you added it manually somehow and your setup is not working? Please add more info to your question to get a meaningful response.)

Comment: Check if you have added the HtmlUnit library to your classpath.

Comment: I'm working in Eclipse, and I've already added the HtmlUnit Jars to the buildpath.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere you shouldn't be using HTMLUnit under Android, since it is very large(10+ jars) But I could be wrong